# Why can't I create a new face connecting the selected vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices

As shown in the picture, I've switched on X-ray，selected all vertices and pressed F, but no new face is created.
After that, I switch off X-ray ,selected the vertices again and pressed F, it works.

what is going on?

（Blender Version 2.91.0）

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there are overlapping duplicated vertices. The first image indicates a selection of 48 vertices, the second one 12.

So you should select all <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> to merge and "by distance".

Comment: Thanks very much.